# Exclude JSR 223 sample from summery report

Tags: jmeter

I have several JSR 223 samplers with scripts inside the Thread group, which doing 
some work before the HTTP requests are invoked.

The problem is that the JSR 233 samplers are included in the final summary report
My question is how can I Exclude those JSR 223 samplers from the final calculations?

**UPDATE**

When I try to set pre processor JSR 223
I'm getting this error as the if controller after the pre processor JSR 223
does not recognize the variable I set in the `vars.put`. it only recognize it when I use JSR 223 sampler.

```
2017/08/24 16:07:37 ERROR - jmeter.control.IfController: If Controller: error while processing [${my_foo_var} >=0]
 org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ; before statement (<cmd>#1)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.runtimeError(DefaultErrorReporter.java:77)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.error(DefaultErrorReporter.java:64)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:188)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:166)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:256)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:243)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:236)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.autoInsertSemicolon(Parser.java:1100)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1077)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:934)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:573)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:511)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2488)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1476)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1465)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.evaluateString(Context.java:1216)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController$RhinoJsEngine.evaluate(IfController.java:105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.evaluateCondition(IfController.java:187)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.next(IfController.java:240)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:222)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:176)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:87)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:247)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can tell Jmeter Listeners to ignore the previous SampleResult using "prev.setIgnore();"
in a JSR223 PostProcessor.

You can use this for all Samplers. This solution works for JMeter 4 and 5

[image: Groovy Post Processor example]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) to remove the unwanted sample(s) from the final report, it has `--exclude-label-regex` parameter where you can provide sampler name(s) pattern(s).

You can install Filter Results Tool (as well as any other plugin) and keep it up-to-date using JMeter Plugins Manager

[[image: JMeter Filter Results Tool[2]]

Assuming successful installation you should be able to find `FilterResults.bat` and `FilterResults.sh` tool startup scripts under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation.

Answer (score 0):

All Samplers are included so you can move your code to JSR 223 Post/Pre Processor and put it under different **existing** Sampler in Hierarchy.

That way the code won't be calculated in reports.

Comment: The thing is that i need to run the script to initialize stuff before running  the 
HTTP samples , inside the http samples i do have pre and port JSR 223
which does not included in the summary

Comment: You add as pre processor and it will execute before

Comment: i try this but the if controller that comes after the Per processor  does not 
recognize the variable i set in the vars.put .
it only recognize it when i use  JSR 223 sample